# Change value of column based on criteria and by group

Tags: r, data.table

My data looks like this:

```
     year month flag group
 1: 1992     6    1     8
 2: 1992     7    0     8
 3: 1992     8    0     8
 4: 1992     9    0     8
 5: 1992    10    0     8
 6: 1992    11    0     8
 7: 1992    12    0     8
 8: 1995     6    0    10
 9: 1995     7    0    11
10: 1995     8    0    11
11: 1995     9    1    11
12: 1995    10    0    11
13: 1995    11    0    11
14: 1995    12    0    11
15: 1998     6    0    13
16: 1998     7    0    13
17: 1998     8    0    13
18: 1998     9    0    13
19: 1998    10    0    13
20: 1998    11    0    13
21: 1998    12    0    13
```

What i need to do is to assign a value of 1 to all the rows that follow the first observation of 1 in the `flag` column, this however needs to also be done by `group`.

As a concrete example, i want this:

```
     year month flag group
 1: 1992     6    1     8
 2: 1992     7    1     8
 3: 1992     8    1     8
 4: 1992     9    1     8
 5: 1992    10    1     8
 6: 1992    11    1     8
 7: 1992    12    1     8
 8: 1995     6    0    10
 9: 1995     7    0    11
10: 1995     8    0    11
11: 1995     9    1    11
12: 1995    10    1    11
13: 1995    11    1    11
14: 1995    12    1    11
15: 1998     6    0    13
16: 1998     7    0    13
17: 1998     8    0    13
18: 1998     9    0    13
19: 1998    10    0    13
20: 1998    11    0    13
21: 1998    12    0    13
```

Notice how rows 1:7 are now 1, as well as 11:14 and also notice how there have been no changes to rows 15:21 seeing how there was no 1 initially.

Most of my ideas have revolved around using `which` to find out the index of the first 1 by group, but i have run into some trouble.

If anyone has any `data.table()` based solutions that'd be great.

I appreciate any help!

Here's a `dput()` of my base data if helpful:

```
library(data.table)

DT = setDT(structure(list(year = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998), month = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), flag = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We return 1 for the rows from the first occurrence where `flag = 1` and the group has at least one `flag = 1`

```
library(data.table)
dt[,flag := +(seq_len(.N)>= which.max(flag == 1) & any(flag == 1)),by = group]

dt

#    year month flag group
# 1: 1992     6    1     8
# 2: 1992     7    1     8
# 3: 1992     8    1     8
# 4: 1992     9    1     8
# 5: 1992    10    1     8
# 6: 1992    11    1     8
# 7: 1992    12    1     8
# 8: 1995     6    0    10
# 9: 1995     7    0    11
#10: 1995     8    0    11
#11: 1995     9    1    11
#12: 1995    10    1    11
#13: 1995    11    1    11
#14: 1995    12    1    11
#15: 1998     6    0    13
#16: 1998     7    0    13
#17: 1998     8    0    13
#18: 1998     9    0    13
#19: 1998    10    0    13
#20: 1998    11    0    13
#21: 1998    12    0    13
#    year month flag group
```

Which in `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(flag = +(row_number() >= which.max(flag == 1) & any(flag == 1)))
```

and in base R using `ave` would be

```
dt$flag <- with(dt, +(ave(flag == 1, group, FUN = function(x) 
                     seq_along(x) >= which.max(x) & any(x))))
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(year = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998), month = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), flag = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = 
c("data.table","data.frame"))
```

Comment: When using your `data.table()` answer i get the following error:

`Error in `[.data.table`(stack_dat, , `:=`(flag, as.integer(seq_len(.N) >=  : 
  Type of RHS ('integer') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)`

Also, it looks like you've grouped by `year` and not the `group` column. Or have i misunderstood your code?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon yes, I had grouped by `year` first. I have changed the group to `group` now though output doesn't change and I do not get an error on the sample data which I have used. It looks like there is a type mismatch try using `as.numeric` instead of `+`,  Try `dt[,flag := as.numeric(seq_len(.N)>= which.max(flag == 1) & any(flag == 1)),by=group]`

Comment: Thanks for that. I've got a couple of questions regarding the code: Why is the `any()` needed and what is the error that I was initially getting related to and what's the difference between `+` and `as.numeric`?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon `which.max` calculates the first maximum value in the vector passed. `flag == 1` returns a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values depending if `flag` is 1 or not, when we do `which.max(flag == 1)` it returns index of first maximum value. So in case if there is any `TRUE` value it would return index of first `TRUE` or else if all the values are `FALSE` then the maximum would be `FALSE` and it would return 1. So in this case it would give 1 to the entire `group`, to avoid that we use `any` and check that if there is any `flag` which has value 1 in the `group`.

Comment: As far as `+` and `as.numeric` is concerned , `+` converts `TRUE/FALSE` values to integer whereas you had numeric values in your column so there was a type mismatch and hence instead of `+` we use `as.numeric` so that the type matches the original columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a non-equi join with the first month per group:

```
DT[unique(DT[flag==1], by="group"), on=.(group, month >= month), flag := 1]
```

This is the result with the dput from the OP:

```
    year month flag group
 1: 1992     1    0     8
 2: 1992     2    0     8
 3: 1992     3    0     8
 4: 1992     4    0     8
 5: 1992     5    0     8
 6: 1992     6    1     8
 7: 1992     7    1     8
 8: 1992     8    1     8
 9: 1992     9    1     8
10: 1992    10    1     8
11: 1992    11    1     8
12: 1992    12    1     8
13: 1995     1    0    10
14: 1995     2    0    10
15: 1995     3    0    10
16: 1995     4    0    10
17: 1995     5    0    10
18: 1995     6    0    10
19: 1995     7    0    11
20: 1995     8    0    11
21: 1995     9    1    11
22: 1995    10    1    11
23: 1995    11    1    11
24: 1995    12    1    11
25: 1998     1    0    13
26: 1998     2    0    13
27: 1998     3    0    13
28: 1998     4    0    13
29: 1998     5    0    13
30: 1998     6    0    13
31: 1998     7    0    13
32: 1998     8    0    13
33: 1998     9    0    13
34: 1998    10    0    13
35: 1998    11    0    13
36: 1998    12    0    13
    year month flag group
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr` and `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(cumsum(flag) > 1, 1, 0))
```

Another way could be by using `lag`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(flag != 1 & row_number() > 1, lag(flag, 1), flag))
```

Or in `data.table` as:

```
df[, flag := ifelse(cumsum(flag) > 1, 1, 0), by=group]
```

Comment: Your `data.table` solution doesn't work for me. It just assigns every value as 0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `na.locf()` from the `zoo` package

Step 1: Filter for groups containing at least one "1" and replace the "0"s in them with NA

Step 2: Use `na.locf()` to drag the most recent non-NA value to everything below

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

temp[group %in% temp[,max(flag),.(group)][V1==1]$group & flag == 0,flag:= NA][,flag:=na.locf(flag,na.rm = FALSE)]
```

Input table (temp)

```
structure(list(year = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998), month = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), flag = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Output table

```
structure(list(year = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998), month = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), flag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```